# GMENU doesn't display images

Tags: typo3, typoscript

GMENU doesn't display images inserted with typoscript. when i look in my page code source I find tha insert an image from typo3temp/menu but the problem that this folder is empty.
my code is:

```
lib.menuhoriz = HMENU
lib.menuhoriz {
     wrap = <div class="themeMenu">|</div>
     entryLevel = 1

     1 = GMENU
     1 {


     NO {
        wrap = <div class="themeMenuItem">|</div>
        37 = IMAGE
        37.file = fileadmin/templates/templatePortail/images/cooperation.gif
    }

   }

}
```

thank you.

Comment: did you check the image processing functionality in the install tool?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to check this functionality, please can you explain more.

Comment: just google for typo3 install tool image processing, there are many  tutorials, many in german, but also some on video